# insert a pointer variable with the size part of the fgets function.what's difference between p and *p?

Tags: c

```
char* cp = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_STR);
FILE* fp = fopen("paren_matching.txt", "r");
while (fgets(cp,cp, fp) != NULL) { }
```

(`MAX_STR` is 100 and the txt file has some sentences)

In this case, I don't understand when `fgets` works only use `cp` in the size part of `fgets`

I used `*cp` but it makes runtime error. `fgets(cp,*cp,fp)!=NULL{}`

I think `cp`'s r-value is address then `*cp`'s r-value is what..?

I'll appreciate it if you could tell me the answer

Comment: Your second argument shouldn't be `cp` nor `*cp`. `char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream) ------ n − This is the maximum number of characters to be read (including the final null-character). Usually, the length of the array passed as str is used.`

Comment: thanks to reply. but i want to using pointer by Dynamic memory allocation. That function works when i use cp.But is it correct to write in the standard format you said?

Comment: `That function works when i use cp.` No, it doesn't. Neiter `cp` nor `*cp` contain the length of your allocated memory. Use `MAX_STR` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for letting me know!! ^3^

Comment: Save time, enable all warnings to quickly know of the trouble with `fgets(cp,cp, fp)`.

Comment: "i want to using pointer by Dynamic memory allocation." --> OK, but "why"?   Knowing the large goal would help steer us to a good answer.

Comment: I thought about why that function works, but the memory address stored in pointer fp is an integer, so I think it works because the memory address value is included in the size part, right?
And I'm a student now, so I don't have a large goal. I wondered if it worked by putting a pointer variable dynamically assigned to the function. Thanks to reply!!

Comment: The call would probably fail if the string to be read was longer than MAX_STR.

Comment: Thank u Mr.stark!!

Answer (score 0):

Because cp is a pointer, *cp is dereference - which basicly means *cp = value that is being pointed at by cp. You used malloc which allocates memory but does not inicialize it to anything. So when you don't put anything inside, it's just garbage there. It could be whatever so it can cause a problem(for example nagative value).
Cp on the other hand is a pointer so it's unsigned number, so it will never cause problems.

In either way it probably doesn't do what you wanted it to. The second argmunent of fgets should be MAX_STR, because that is how much you allocated.

Comment: Thanks to you, i clearly understand my mistake!!